# Execute some code for each request for ASP.NET (aspx and cshtml )

Tags: asp.net, razor, global-asax, iis-8

Is there a way to write some code that would be executed for each request to a .aspx or a .cshtml page in asp.net 4.5 **apart from using a base page class**. it is a very huge project and making changes to all pages to use a base page is a nightmare. Also i am not sure how would this be done for a cshtml page since they don't have  a class.

Can we use the **Application_BeginRequest** and target only the aspx and cshtml files since the website is running in integrated mode.?

basically, i have to check if a user who is accessing the website has a specific ip address against a database and if yes then allow access otherwise redirect.

we are using IIS8 and ASP.Net 4.5 and ASP.Net Razor Web Pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also i am not sure how would this be done for a cshtml page since they don't have a class.

You could place a `_ViewStart.cshtml` file whose contents will get executed on each request.

Alternatively you could write a [`custom Http Module`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307996):

```
public class MyModule: IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication app)
    {
        app.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(OnBeginRequest);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    { 

    }   

    public void OnBeginRequest(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this code here's gonna get executed on each request
    }
}
```

and then simply register this module in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="MyModule" type="SomeNamespace.MyModule, SomeAssembly" />
    </modules>
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

or if you are running in Classic Mode:

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="MyModule" type="SomeNamespace.MyModule, SomeAssembly" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

> basically, i have to check if a user who is accessing the website has
>   a specific ip address against a database and if yes then allow access
>   otherwise redirect.

Inside the `OnBeginRequest` method you could get the current user IP:

```
    public void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var app = sender as HttpApplication;
        var request = app.Context.Request;
        string ip = request.UserHostAddress;
        // do your checks against the database
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net MVC filters are especially designed for that purpose.

You would implement ActionFilterAttribute like this (maybe put this new class in a Filters folder in your webapp solution):

```
public class IpFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string ip = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress;

        if(!testIp(ip))
        {
            if (true /* You want to use a route name*/)
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("badIpRouteName");
            else /* you want an url */
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/badIpController/badIpAction");
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
    private bool testIp(string inputIp)
    {
        return true /* do you ip test here */;
    }
}
```

Then you have to decorate any action that would perform the ipcheck with IpFilter like so :

```
    [IpFilter]
    public ActionResult AnyActionWhichNeedsGoodIp()
    {
         /* do stuff */
    }
```